# RecyclerView not scrolling top top when new item inserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView which allows swipe-to-delete functionality. After deliting, a Snackbar shows to confirm deletion with an action that allows users to "undo" the delete.

Everything works fine until I delete the item at position 0 then hit `undo`. The item will be reinserted back into the list but users will need to scroll up to bring it back into view.

### What I have tried

- Setting `recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled"` on the RecyclerView
- Using `layoutCoordinator.scrollTo(0, 0)` on the Coordinator Layout
- Using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` on the RecyclerView
- Using `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` on the RecyclerView
- Using `recyclerView.scrollTo(0, 0)` on the RecyclerView
- Using `itemAdapter.notifiyItemInserted(0)` on the Adapter
- Using `itemAdapter.notifiyItemchanged(0)` on the Adapter
- Using `itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter
- Using `layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)` on the
  LayoutManager
- Creating a custom `LayoutManager` and overriding
  `smoothScrollToPosotion()` with my own implementation.

None of the above have offered a solution.

---

Below are the workings.

## ItemsFragment

Inside `onCreateView` - here is setting up the `itemAdapter` and `recyclerView`:

```
    val itemAdapter = object : ItemRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        override fun onItemClicked(item: Item) {
            // todo
        }
    }

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter
```

Here is my `swipeToDeleteCallback` with `Snackbar` action to "undo" the delete:

```
val swipeToDeleteCallback = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val item = itemAdapter.currentList[position]
            viewModel.deleteItem(item)

            val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                recyclerView,
                getString(R.string.snackbar_msg_deleted_card),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            )
            snackBar.setAction(R.string.snack_bar_undo) {
                viewModel.restoreItem(item)
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
            }
            snackBar.show()
        }
    }
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback)
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Setting the items which are LiveData observed from the ViewModel. Changes are immediately passed to the adapter:

```
val items = viewModel.items.await()
    items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            itemAdapter.setItems(it)
        }
    })
```

## ItemsAdapter

Submitting the list with DiffUtilCallback:

```
fun setItems(list: List<Item>?) {
    adapterScope.launch {
        val itemsList = when(list) {
            null -> emptyList()
            else -> list.sortedByDescending {
                it.itemId
            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            submitList(itemsList)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Temporary fix

So far the only thing that has worked is this hacky solution inside my `Snackbar` action:

```
snackBar.setAction(R.string.snack_bar_undo) {
                viewModel.restoreItem(item)
                if (position == 0) {
                    itemsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
                }
            }
```

Here I'm checking if the item `position` is `0`. If so then telling the adapter that there's a new `item` inserted at `position 0` - then initiating scrolling. Otherwise, don't do anything because items at any `position` other than `0` will insert and animate fine beceause of the `DiffUtilCallback`.

This temporary fix works but the scrolling is "snappy" and produces an error in the logs:

> RecyclerView: Passed over target position while smooth scrolling

Also, this solution does not work 100% of the time. It's more like 60% of the time.

Does anybody know of a better solution/something I am missing and a way to resolve the error above?